# Changing hardcoded array to a $http callback

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, global-variables, ionic-framework

i am wanting to change my service from a hardcoded static array to an array returned from a $http call. i have attempted to do this below however it does not work.

I can confirm the data returned from http is working and returns the correct data( i have taken the link out for the purpose of the question).

i am not getting an error message and therefore cannot give any further information at this point however what i would like to know is if i am doing this in the correct way.

banging my head against a wall for such a simple task at the moment....

hardcorded array:

```
.factory('Cards', function($http){
  var cardTypes = [
    {id: 1, USECASE_NAME: "Frank", USECASE_IMAGE: 'img/Frank.png', USECASE_DESC:"This is frank the bank card, He helps people all over the world make millions of transactions each year!", done: true },
    {id: 2, USECASE_NAME: "John Lewis", USECASE_IMAGE: 'img/JohnLewis.png', USECASE_DESC:"John Lewis is one of the biggest retailers in the United Kingdom with a very proud reputation", done: true },
    {id: 3, USECASE_NAME: "Generali", USECASE_IMAGE: 'img/Generali.png', USECASE_DESC:"Generali is the largest insurance company in Italy and arguably one of the biggest in Europe", done: true },

  ];
  return {
    all: function() {
      return cardTypes;
    }
  }

});
```

$http callback

```
.factory('Cards', function($http) {
    var cardTypes = {};

    $http.post("http://url", {
        "auth": "cats",
        "name": "Adam",
        "uuid": "fasfA"
    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        cardTypes = data;
    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });

    return {
        all: function() {
            return cardTypes;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that `.http()` is an asynchronous call. So calling `.all()` directly after initalizing the factory will result in returning an empty object, because the post request is probably still pending when `.all()` is called.

I would recommend using a service (a factory is possible as well, but imo a service would fit better here) and returning the promise like:

```
this.getAll = function() {
    return $http.post("http://url",{"auth":"cats","name":"Adam","uuid": "fasfA" });
}
```

Then in your controller you can do this:

```
Cards.getAll().then(function(c){
     $scope.cards = c;
})
```

Comment: iv used cardTypes as a global variable in my app and everything reads and writes from this 

would i be able to handle this within a service?

Comment: Yes, just like in your factory.

Comment: Hi Florian, sorry i am still confused about this. how would i go about using a service in this way without it just being the same as my factory?

Comment: Don't hang up on my suggestion of using a service. The solution of your problem is to work with the `http.post()`s `promise` by returning it instead of it's result (`return cardTypes`), because you don't know when `cardTypes` is filled.